# Variables in snipMate definition, is it possible? (vim)

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, snipmate

I use vim for programming purposes and I use the [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) utility. I'm aware of the basic snippets definition, but I'm trying to do something like the following (this doesn't work):

```
snippet ${1}_.
    <$1 class="${2}">${3}</$1>
```

I think it would be easier to explain with an example. What I'm trying to do is to insert a html tag when typing a word followed by `_.` :

So if I type `div_.` and press tab, it should change to:

```
<div class="(position of cursor)">(position of cursor)</div>
```

If I type `span_.` and press tab, it should change to:

```
<span class="(position of cursor)">(position of cursor)</span>
```

And so on. Hope you get the idea. I'm aware that I can write a snippet for every case, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make the snippet do the hard work for you:

```
snippet tag
    <${1:div} class="${2}">${3}</$1>
```

You may also want to take a look at [emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) and [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).

Comment: Although this is not exactly what I wanted to achieve, it's a pretty good workaround. I'm not gonna accept your answer just yet in case someone comes around with a perfect solution. I took a look at surround.vim and is quite an interesting useful tool! Thanks!